# number theory Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

I need help understanding an old homework question.
It said to find all the solutions $$x^2 + y^2 = 3z^2 + 3t^2$$

My professor said for $x^2 + y^2 >0$ the LHS is divisible to 3 to an even power but the RHS is divisible by 3 to an odd power. So $x^2 + y^2 = 3z^2 + 3t^2$ only has a solution when $x=y=z=t=0$

I am not sure how this came out to be the answer but this was the theorem that was applied:
Suppose $$n = 2^{u0} p_1^{u1}...p_s^{us}q_1^{r1}...q_l^{rl}$$ where p and q are primes.  Here $p_i = 1\ mod\ 4$ and $q_i = 3\ mod\ 4$. Then there exists integers x and y sucht that $x^2 + y^2 =n$ iff $2|r_j$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the squares $\pmod 3$ are $0,1$, so the only way the sum of two squares can be divisible by $3$ is if both the squares are divisible by $3$.  Then both $x^2$ and $y^2$ are divisible by $9$.  We can divide the equation by $3$ to get $3(\frac x3)^2+3(\frac y3)^2=z^2+t^2$  This is the same equation with a smaller solution.  We can continue the descent, concluding there is no smallest solution except $0$.